# Unable to encode for substitution cypher

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic cypher but I'm stuck on how to get it to encode and decode the data. Here's what I have so far:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
alpha = list(alpha)
print("secret decoder menu")

def encode(key, alpha):
    keyIndices = [alpha.index(k.lower()) for k in alpha]
    return ''.join(key[keyIndex] for keyIndex in keyIndices)
 
plain = input("text to be encoded: ")
print(encode(plain, key))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 File "/home/Deshwill/.pythonstartup.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/Deshwill/.pythonstartup.py", line 32, in main
    print(encode(plain, key))
  File "/home/Deshwill/.pythonstartup.py", line 11, in encode
    keyIndices = [alpha.index(k.lower()) for k in alpha]
  File "/home/Deshwill/.pythonstartup.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    keyIndices = [alpha.index(k.lower()) for k in alpha]
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Hint: What happens when your input isn't purely uppercase alphabetic letters? What does `alpha.index(' ')` do? Side-note: `str.maketrans` (once up front) + `str.translate` (called once per input string) is usually the best way to do substitution ciphers like this.

Comment: The index is just a way to search for given elements, right? I'm sorry I'm still very new at this.

Comment: If you're new, get used to loading up the interactive interpreter (`ipython` if you can; it's a lot more friendly by default) and actually trying out small snippets to figure out what's going wrong. You shouldn't have needed to guess at what happens, try it out.